# Why dd returns bad address error with /dev/mem?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I run an embedded linux-3.10.29 on a PowerPC board (big-endian). To debug my ethernet controller, I need to check some system registers. The SoC system registers lies at address `0xe0000000` (3584M). So I disabled CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM in linux config and ran:

```
$ dd if=/dev/mem of=/home/mem.dump bs=1024 count=1k skip=3584k
dd: /dev/mem: Bad address
```

This command should skip the first (3584k * 1024B =) 3584MB from `/dev/mem` and copy the leading (1k * 1024B =) 1MB to `/home/mem.dump`. I also tried to dump various 4kB ranges inside the overall 1MB, leading to the same issue.

This memory space is widely ioremapped by my kernel. Although I am not quite sure this is a problem.

```
# cat /proc/iomem 
00000000-0fffffff : System RAM
80000000-8fffffff : /pci@e0008500
  80000000-8007ffff : 0000:00:10.0
90000000-9fffffff : /pci@e0008500
  90000000-900003ff : 0000:00:10.0
    90000000-900003ff : sata_sil
e0004500-e0004507 : serial
e0004600-e0004607 : serial
f8000000-ffffffff : physmap-flash.0
  f8000000-ffffffff : physmap-flash.0

# cat /proc/vmallocinfo 
0xd1000000-0xd1002000    8192 ipic_init+0x98/0x198 phys=e0000000 ioremap
0xd1004000-0xd1006000    8192 mpc83xx_restart_init+0x1c/0x38 phys=e0000000 ioremap
0xd1006000-0xd1008000    8192 serial_dev_init+0x118/0x168 phys=e0004000 ioremap
0xd1008000-0xd100a000    8192 serial_dev_init+0x118/0x168 phys=e0004000 ioremap
0xd100a000-0xd100c000    8192 of_iomap+0x30/0x54 phys=e0005000 ioremap
0xd100c000-0xd100e000    8192 pcim_iomap+0x5c/0x7c phys=90000000 ioremap
0xd100e000-0xd1010000    8192 of_fsl_spi_probe+0x394/0x574 phys=e0007000 ioremap
0xd1010000-0xd1012000    8192 of_iomap+0x30/0x54 phys=e0024000 ioremap
0xd1012000-0xd1014000    8192 of_iomap+0x30/0x54 phys=e0025000 ioremap
0xd1014000-0xd1016000    8192 of_iomap+0x30/0x54 phys=e0024000 ioremap
0xd1016000-0xd1018000    8192 of_iomap+0x30/0x54 phys=e0025000 ioremap
0xd1018000-0xd101a000    8192 of_iomap+0x30/0x54 phys=e0003000 ioremap
0xd101a000-0xd101c000    8192 of_iomap+0x30/0x54 phys=e0003000 ioremap
0xd1080000-0xd9081000 134221824 devm_ioremap+0x44/0x9c phys=f8000000 ioremap
```

I have an alternative called `mem_util` and @tangrs taught me that `devmem` provides the same functionality. But what is this `bad address` issue with `dd`?

[EDIT]

```
$ strace dd if=/dev/mem of=/home/mem.dump bs=1024 count=1k skip=3584k
[...]
_llseek(0, 3758096384, [3758096384], SEEK_CUR) = 0
read(0, 0x100b1008, 1024)               = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `devmem` to check registers? It was designed for this purpose.

Comment: 'cause I wanted to understand what's wrong with `dd`. I have a tool called `mem_util` which does the same thing as `devmem`. I didn't know about `devmem`. Thanks.

Comment: run `dd` under `strace` and see if something you don't expect is going on (in particular for the lseek() and read() calls). I'm a bit puzzled that your /proc/iomem doesn't show mappings for your device though, is it remapped somewhere other than 0xe0000000 ?

Comment: my dev is this one: `0xd1010000-0xd1012000 8192 of_iomap phys=e0024000 ioremap`. I updated my question with strace result.

Comment: Then shouldn't you rather read data starting at memory address 0xd1010000 as that's where it's mapped ? (Or possibly at 0xe0024000) There's nothing here that indicates there's anything to read at address 0xe0000000